# How to ByPass "No subject alternative names present" in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, ssl, tcp, spring-integration

I have a project which uses Spring Integration communicates over TCP with my client. My client requests me to use SSL at this TCP communication. When I tried a TCP connection over SSL, I got No subject alternative names present error.

I added this code block to bypass that check:

```
import org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.security.KeyManagementException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

public class CustomTCPSSLContextSupport extends DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport {
    public CustomTCPSSLContextSupport(String keyStore, String trustStore, String keyStorePassword, String trustStorePassword) {
        super(keyStore, trustStore, keyStorePassword, trustStorePassword);
    }

    @Override
    public SSLContext getSSLContext() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }
        };

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        return sc;
    }
}
```

I defined it like this:

```
<bean id="sslContextSupport" class="CustomTCPSSLContextSupport">
    <constructor-arg value="${keystore.path}"/>
    <constructor-arg value="${cacerts.path}"/>
    <constructor-arg value="changeit"/>
    <constructor-arg value="changeit"/>
</bean>
```

I used this sslContextSupport as ssl-context-support in my tcp-connection-factory but no affect. It still gives same error.

How can I bypass subject alternative check completely in Spring Integration?

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to see the whole stack trace to be sure that your `CustomTCPSSLContextSupport` is really in use.

Although I see that typically they implement "trust all" like this:

```
static class TrustAllX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {
    TrustAllX509TrustManager() {
    }

    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {
    }

    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {
    }

    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}
```

An empty array for `new X509Certificate[0]`, not `null` like in your case.

The `sc.init()` looks OK to me.